# How to promote a batch of students from a semester to another?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, codeigniter

I want promote a batch of students from semester 1 to semester 2.

---------------Controller--------------------

```html
public function display_promote_student()
    {   
      if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] === true && $_SESSION['role'] === '1' && $_SESSION['role_des'] === 'admin')
      {
         $data['batch']=$this->Student_model->get_all_batch();
         $data['course']=$this->Student_model->get_all_course();
         $data['sem']=$this->Student_model->get_all_sem();
         if($data)
          {
             $this->load->view('Admin/header');     
             $this->load->view('Admin/promote_students', $data);
          }
          else
          {
            redirect('Admin/index','refresh'); 
          }
      }
      else
      {
      redirect('Admin/index');
      }
    }
  public function list_promote_student_view()
    { 
      if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] === true && $_SESSION['role'] === '1' && $_SESSION['role_des'] === 'admin')
      {
          $course=$this->input->post('course');
          $sem=$this->input->post('sem');
          $batch=$this->input->post('batch');
          $data['course']=$course;
          $data['sem']=$sem;
          $data['batch']=$batch;
          $data['promote'] = $this->Student_model->get_all_student_by_cour_sem($course,$sem,$batch);
          $this->load->view('Admin/header');     
          $this->load->view('Admin/list_promote_students',$data);
      }
    }
  public function promote_semester_processing()
    { 
      if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] === true && $_SESSION['role'] === '1' && $_SESSION['role_des'] === 'admin')
      {
        $course=$this->input->post('course');
        $sem=$this->input->post('sem');
        $batch=$this->input->post('batch');
        $new_sem=$this->input->post('newsem');
        $results = $this->Student_model->get_all_student_by_cour_sem($course,$sem,$batch);
        $dep_id = [$results];
        //var_dump( $dep_id);die();
        $prodate = date('Y-m-d');
        $month = strtotime($prodate);
        $promonth = date('m',$month);
        foreach($results  as  $val)
        {
          $dep_id = $val['student_id'];
          $db_date = $val['promote_date'];
          $db_month =  strtotime($db_date);
          $pro_month = date('m',$db_month);
          $cal = $pro_month +5;
          $data = array(
                  'sem_id' =>$new_sem,
                  'promote_date' =>$prodate);
          if($db_date == 0)
          {
              $id=$this->Student_model->update_semester($dep_id,$data);
              if($id)
              {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Promote Semester Successfully... </div>');    
                redirect('Admin/display_promote_student');
              } 
              else
              {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Promote Semester not Successfully... </div>');    
                redirect('Admin/display_promote_student');
              }
            }
          elseif ($promonth == $cal) 
          {
              $id=$this->Student_model->update_semester($dep_id,$data);
          }
          else
          {
             $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You can promote only after six months... </div>');    
             redirect('Admin/display_promote_student');
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I have tables student, course, semester, batch

-------------------Model---------------------

```html
public function get_all_student_by_cour_sem($course,$sem,$batch)
  {
    $this->db->select( 'tbl_student.*, tbl_course.*,tbl_semester.*,tbl_batch.*');    
    $this->db->from('tbl_student'); 
    $this->db->join('tbl_course','tbl_course.course_id = tbl_student.course_id','left');
    $this->db->join('tbl_semester', 'tbl_semester.sem_id = tbl_student.sem_id','left');
    $this->db->join('tbl_batch', 'tbl_batch.batch_id = tbl_student.stud_batch_id','left');
    $this->db->where('tbl_student.course_id',$course);
    $this->db->where('tbl_student.sem_id',$sem);
    $this->db->where('tbl_student.stud_batch_id',$batch);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array(); 
  }
  public function update_semester($dep_id,$data)
  {
    $this->db->where('student_id',$dep_id);
    return  $query = $this->db->update('tbl_student',$data);
  }
```

-------------------------views------------------------

promote_student

```html
<div class="container">
     <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
     <h4><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?></h4><br>
<div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3>Promote Students</h3>
            </div>
            <?php $attributes = array("name" => "promote", "class" => "form-horizontal");
                echo form_open_multipart("Admin/list_promote_student_view", $attributes);?>
              <div class="panel-body">
                   <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                  <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Course</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select class="form-control" name="course" required>
      <option>--Choose a Course--</option>
                  <?php 
     foreach($course as $row)
     { 
       echo '<option value="'.$row->course_id.'">'.$row->c_name.'</option>';
     }?>
      </select>
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('course'); ?></span>
                  </div>
        </div>
     
               <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                  <label for="semester" class="col-sm-2 control-label" placeholder="">Semester</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
       
                    <select class="form-control" name="sem" required>
<option>--Choose a Semester--</option>
                  <?php 
     foreach($sem as $row)
     { 
       echo '<option value="'.$row->sem_id.'">'.$row->sem_code.'</option>';
     }?>
       </select>
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('semester'); ?></span>
                  </div>
      </div>
         <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                  <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Year</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <select class="form-control" name="batch" required>
                     <option>--Choose Batch--</option>
                  <?php 
     foreach($batch as $row)
     { 
       echo '<option value="'.$row->batch_id.'">'.$row->batch_year.'</option>';
     }?>
                  </select>
                    </div>
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('year'); ?></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              <div class="box-footer col-md-offset-4">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Submit</button>
              </div>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
```

List_promote_students

```html
<div class="container">
 <a  href="<?php echo base_url('Admin/display_promote_student');?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-flat margin pull-right">Previous</a>
 <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3>Student List</h3>
            </div> 
            <div class="panel-body">
    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Serial no</th>
      <th>Student Name</th>
                  <th>Course</th>
      <th>Semester</th> 
      <th>Batch</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
      <tbody>
                  <?php 
          $i=1;   
         foreach ($promote as $row)  
         {   
            ?>
                <tr>
      <td><?php echo $i++;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['stud_name'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['c_name'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['sem_code'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['batch_year'];?></td> 
    </tr>
 <?php }  
         ?>  
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php $attributes = array("name" => "update");
        echo form_open("Admin/promote_semester_processing", $attributes);?>
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $course;?>" name="course"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sem;?>" name="sem"/>
     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $batch;?>" name="batch"/>
      <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Semester</label>
                     <select class="form-control" name="newsem" required data-placeholder="Semester">
                      <option>--Semester--</option>
                      <option value="1">s1</option>
                      <option value="2">s2</option>
                      <option value="3">s3</option>
                      <option value="4">s4</option>
                      <option value="5">s5</option>
                      <option value="6">s6</option>
                    </select>
        </div>
     <button name="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >Promote Semester</button>
  <?php  echo form_close(); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Only one student is getting promoted with this code. But I want to promote a batch of students into next semester. How do I do that?

Please help me as early as possible.

Comment: I think this is wày to much code. Can you post only the most relevant lines?

Comment: Tip asking question the run code snippets for javascript, html, css not php if you need to add code you can add it this way https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are updating the students one by one using a loop, but you should use the codeigniter's **update_batch** function inside your model's **update_semester($dep_id,$data)** function. Also you have to pass all students data in the $data parameter.

[Codeigniter update_batch function link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data)

**Issue in your code**:-
The issue is in your controller's **promote_semester_processing()** function. In the **foreach loop** whenever the first user's semester is updated successfully then you are using a **redirect('Admin/display_promote_student');** after setting the flash data **$this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Promote Semester Successfully... ');** which refreshes the page, hence the next update query will never execute.

**Updated promote_semester_processing() function after your comment**

```
public function promote_semester_processing()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] === true && $_SESSION['role'] === '1' && $_SESSION['role_des'] === 'admin')
    {
        $course=$this->input->post('course');
        $sem=$this->input->post('sem');
        $batch=$this->input->post('batch');
        $new_sem=$this->input->post('newsem');
        $results = $this->Student_model->get_all_student_by_cour_sem($course,$sem,$batch);
        $dep_id = [$results];
        //var_dump( $dep_id);die();
        $prodate = date('Y-m-d');
        $month = strtotime($prodate);
        $promonth = date('m',$month);


        $response_array = array();    // Declare an empty array to store all responses


        foreach($results  as  $val)
        {
            $dep_id = $val['student_id'];
            $db_date = $val['promote_date'];
            $db_month =  strtotime($db_date);
            $pro_month = date('m',$db_month);
            $cal = $pro_month +5;
            $data = array(
                'sem_id' =>$new_sem,
                'promote_date' =>$prodate
            );


            if($db_date == 0)
            {
                $id=$this->Student_model->update_semester($dep_id,$data);
                if($id)
                {
                    //$this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Promote Semester Successfully... </div>');    

                    //redirect('Admin/display_promote_student');



                    $response_array[] = array(
                        'student_id' => $dep_id,    // you can use anything here according to your requirement
                        'msg' => '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Promote Semester Successfully... </div>'
                    );

                }
                else
                {
                    //$this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Promote Semester not Successfully... </div>');

                    //redirect('Admin/display_promote_student');



                    $response_array[] = array(
                        'student_id' => $dep_id,    // you can use anything here according to your requirement
                        'msg' => '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Promote Semester not Successfully... </div>'
                    );
                }
            }
            elseif ($promonth == $cal)
            {
                $id=$this->Student_model->update_semester($dep_id,$data);
            }
            else
            {
                //$this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You can promote only after six months... </div>');

                //redirect('Admin/display_promote_student');



                $response_array[] = array(
                    'student_id' => $dep_id,    // you can use anything here according to your requirement
                    'msg' => '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You can promote only after six months... </div>'
                );
            }
        }



        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $response_array);
        redirect('Admin/display_promote_student');
    }
}
```

As i have used an array for flashdata, So you have to change the code on the redirected page accordingly.

**Some Guidance**

1- You should use codeigniter [form_validation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html) library.

2- Use update_batch function whenever you want to update multiple rows in database.

Comment: Instead of redirect('Admin/display_promote_student'); what will be set after the flashdata. I remove the redirect code, the output  students are promoting but a plain  page will be displaying.

Comment: @ZelahAsher According to your current implementation you can declare an empty array before the foreach loop, and then fill this array with messages inside the foreach loop (don't use "flashdata" and "redirect" at this point). After the foreach loop is completed you can set the flashdata with newly created array, and then simply redirect.